# SDL2 - Updating part of a texture is slower than updating all of it

Tags: c++, textures, optimization, sdl2, streaming

I'm programing a kind of cellular automaton in which each pixel is an automaton.

I'm using a SDL2 [streaming texture](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING) with the `SDL_LockTexture()` and `SDL_UnlockTexture()` methods to "open" the whole texture and draw the full 426x240 array of pixels. Like this:

```
  // inside update() method
  world_texture_.lock((void**)&world_pixels_, &texture_pitch_);

  for (int i = rows_ - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols_; ++j) {
      const auto current_index {getIndex(i, j)};
      checkAutomatons(current_index); // this checks stuff and changes world_pixels_ accordingly
    }
  }

  world_texture_.unlock();
```

Lately I figured out that I don't need to update the whole texture, as the vast majority of pixels weren't changing from frame to frame. So I made a method to create an `SDL_Rect` around the area that needs to be updated, drastically decreasing the number of pixels to check. Like this:

```
 // inside update() method
 world_texture_.lock(&bounding_box_, (void**)&world_pixels_, &texture_pitch_);

 for (int i = bounding_box_.y + bounding_box_.h - 1; i >= bounding_box_.y; --i) {
   for (int j = bounding_box_.x; j < bounding_box_.x + bounding_box_.w; ++j) {
     const auto current_index {getIndex(i, j)};
     checkAutomatons(current_index);
   }
 }
 
 world_texture_.unlock();
```

But to my surprise, this "precision" way is doing slower than checking every pixel and updating the whole texture. Profiling gives me an average of 0.001537s for the whole texture and 0.003079s for the "precision" way. You may think that my algorithm to determine the area to be updated makes it go slower, but the algorithm is running in both versions, but only the "precision" one is using the rectangle generated.

Why could this be? Reading the SDL2 [docs](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_LockTexture) it seems the correct way to change a texture that is being updated often. Maybe is because the range of the for loops changes at every `update()` call and some register or other low-level thing gets changed/updated?

Comment: I don't know SDL, but in other APIs this can be expected behaviour as updating a full resource allows the API to make optimizations such as not needing to preserve data in the regions that aren't updated; it can also make other optimizations if the resource is currently in use for drawing (such as allocating a new resource rather than having to block and synchronize).  Graphics are often counter-intuitive like that, and I wouldn't be at all surprised if this was exactly what you're seeing here.

Comment: If update speed is a concern, [I'd be tempted to move the whole update logic to a shader](https://twitter.com/D_M_Gregory/status/802340525714063360), so you don't have to lock it for CPU read/write at all.